# How can I determine which index on a DB2 table is clustered

Tags: database, db2

How can I determine which, if any, index on an existing DB2 v9.7 (for LUW) table is the clustering index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about DB2 for z/OS (because your statement about clustering indexes is only valid for that product), you can query the catalog table:

```
select name from sysibm.sysindexes where tbname='WHATEVER' and clustering='Y'
```

EDIT:

The question was revised to indicate that the DB2 version in question is 9.7 for LUW. In that case the catalog *view* to query is:

```
select indname from syscat.indexes where indextype='CLUS'
```

Comment: To clarify:  DB2 for LUW does not have an *implicit* clustering index in that it won't automatically try to cluster data if you have not identified a clustering index.  However, if there is no clustering index defined, `REORG` in DB2 LUW will select the oldest index to for ordering the data in the reorganized table.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde -- Could you provide a reference regarding the "oldest index"? The [manual states](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001966.html?lang=en): _If you do not specify the name of an index, the records are reorganized without regard to order. If the table has a clustering index defined, however, and no index is specified, then the clustering index is used to cluster the table._

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question as I am using DB2 v9.7 for LUW, so my understanding was incorrect that the first index defined serves implicitly as the clustered index. I do not see the "clustering" column in sysibm.sysindexes, but there is a "clusterratio" column and a "clusterfactor" column.

Comment: In DB2 for LUW it is recommended to query SYSCAT views instead of the underlying SYSIBM tables, because the latter change frequently.

Comment: @mustaccio I stand corrected.  I could have sworn the documents used to say that, but even going back to ancient docs reveals that my memory must be faulty.  <sigh>

Comment: @IanBjorhovde -- no problem, I was just curious if that was one of those obscure "documented elsewhere" things.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde perhaps you're thinking of [DB2 for z/OS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_clusteringindexes.dita?lang=en): *Although a table can have several indexes, only one index can be a clustering index. If you do not define a clustering index for a table, DB2 recognizes the first index that is created on the table as the implicit clustering index when it orders data rows.*

Answer (score 1):

The SYSCAT.INDEXES table has a column INDEXTYPE that will indicate the type of index.

Usually it will have REG.

If Clustered Index, it will have CLUS.

Here is the documentation
[Catalog view - SYSCAT.INDEXES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001047.html)

============================

1. BLOK = Block index
2. CLUS = Clustering index (controls the physical placement of newly inserted rows)
3. DIM = Dimension block index
4. REG = Regular index
5. XPTH = XML path index
6. XRGN = XML region index
7. XVIL = Index over XML column (logical)
8. XVIP = Index over XML column (physical)